# Bind boolean value in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, binding

I want to bind an expression to a ng-disabled or ng-class attribute and have it re-evaluate whenever the properties change. If I have the expression in the html it all works but makes for terrible readability:

```html
<div ng-class="{disabled: $ctrl.form.$valid && $ctrl.foo && $ctrl.bar && $ctrl.goo }" >
  bla bla bla
</div>
<button ng-disabled="$ctrl.form.$valid && $ctrl.foo && $ctrl.bar && $ctrl.goo" />
```

I'd prefer to have a property in my class definition:

```
this.isValid = this.form.$valid && this.foo && this.bar && this.goo;
```

and bind to this property like so :

```html
<div ng-class="$ctrl.isValid" >
  bla bla bla
</div>
<button ng-disabled="$ctrl.isValid" />
```

If I do the latter the expression only evaluates once when the controller evaluates. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: try setting up a watcher for all of those booleans, e.g. `$scope.$watchGroup` or `$scope.$watchCollection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have it in one place and expression is really weird I would suggest using method:

```
<button ng-disabled="$ctrl.isValid()" />
```

If you need this lots of times in one template - then `$watch`

```
var vm = this;
$scope.$watch('$ctrl.form.$valid && $ctrl.foo && $ctrl.bar && $ctrl.goo', (val) => {
  vm.isValid = val;
});
```

But better do not chain such watchers.